# How do I change the order of a container in mobile with this code?

Tags: html, css

How do I change the order of this code in mobile?

Currently on desktop `<div class="grid4-12">`(left) and `<div class="grid8-12">`(right) are stacked to each other.
How do I change the code in responsive such that `<div class="grid8-12">` is on top and `<div class="grid4-12">` is at the bottom?

Code below

```html
<div class="card-content-lg" style=" background: #ffffff;">
  <div class="grid4-12">
    <div class="quote-wrapper test">
      <div class="quote-col1 test">
        <div class="quote-image"><img alt="Image1" src="/images" /></div>
      </div>

      <div class="quote-col2 test2">
        <div class="quote-text">This is only test</div>
      </div>

      <div class="quote-col3">
        <div><img alt="ABC" src="/images" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid8-12">
    <div class="card-content-md">
      <h2 class="abc">This is h2 text</h2>

      <p>This is a test.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the parent class (.card-content-lg) a display value of flex, with flex-direction set to column. Then, on the "second" / "right" element, give it a value of "order: -1;". Then, change the value of flex-direction to "row" on larger viewports, and change the order back to 1.

```css
.card-content-lg {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 640px) {
    .card-content-lg {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
    }

    .grid4-12, .grid8-12 {
      background: gray;
      min-height: 6rem;
      margin: 1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      color: white;
    }

    .grid8-12 {
      order: -1;
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 640px) {
      .grid8-12 {
        order: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card-content-lg" style=" background: #ffffff;">
      <div class="grid4-12">
        <div class="quote-wrapper test">
          <div class="quote-col1 test">
            <div class="quote-image"><img alt="Image1" src="/images" /></div>
          </div>

          <div class="quote-col2 test2">
            <div class="quote-text">This is only test</div>
          </div>

          <div class="quote-col3">
            <div><img alt="ABC" src="/images" /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid8-12">
        <div class="card-content-md">
          <h2 class="abc">This is h2 text</h2>

          <p>This is a test.</p>

        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou. I used both suggestions and worked it. out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

make `card-content-lg` a flexbox and use media queries to reverse direction using `flex-direction: row-reverse`
add css of your code so we can attach a working sample as well.